# Magento2: Import images & set hidden status ?

Tags: magento2, product-images

I import images in Magento 2 via CSV and this works for base, small and thumb image, just fine! However, in the product view, all three images are shown, as opposed to only the base image. This way, I see three different versions of the same picture in each product page. 
When I manually change this and export the product via CSV, i don't see any difference. 
Any ideas?
Thanks :)
Mike

Answer (score 5):

I've had success on Magento 2.1.11.

1. Create a column in your import file with the heading "hide_from_product_page".
2. List the images in this column that you want excluded from the product page.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this when I first was able to successfully import from 1.9x to 2x and there was nothing in the forums or online yet.

I finally found a way to do it in bulk (i had about 70k+ products) by running an SQL command without compromising any other data (at least from what I could tell)

MYSQL TABLE:  `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`

`disabled=0`

Answer (score 2):

You need to run this SQL query:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value SET disabled = '0' WHERE disabled = '1'
```